# do calculations for multiple columns with some conditions in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My question is relevant to my previous question. But it is different. So, I created a new post even though the data is same.

I would like to do some calculations for multiple columns with some conditions in pandas dataframe.

my table:

```
 id1       date_time               adress       a_size       flag 
 reom      2005-8-20 22:51:10      75157.5413   ceifwekd      1 
 reom      2005-8-20  1:01:25      3571.37946   ceifwekd      1 
 reom      2005-8-20 11:21:01      3571.37946   tnohcve       0
 reom      2005-8-20  8:29:09      97439.219    tnohcve       0
 penr      2005-8-20  17:07:16     97439.219    ceifwekd      1
 penr      2005-8-20  9:10:37      7391.6258    ceifwekd      0
```

I need to  get the percentage of flag == 1 by "address" :

```
  df['ratio'] = df['address'].map(df.groupby('address').apply(lambda x: x[x['flag'] == 1].count() / x['flag'].count()))
```

But I got error:

```
  TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

thanks

Comment: why >  self.__df?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `df.groupby('address')['flag'].mean()`.

Answer (score 0):

I will using `transform` with `mean`

```
  df['ratio'] = df.groupby('address')['flag'].transform('mean')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `transform`:

`df['ratio'] = df.groupby('address').transform(lambda x: x[x['flag'] == 1].count() / x['flag'].count())`